# Calling Google adwords api from Java

Tags: java, api, google-ads-api

I am trying to run simple GetCampaigns.java to get a list of campaigns using Google API.I was able to download google provided API's into eclipse and everything seems to be good in terms of code but when I run the code in eclipse getting error

```
 Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: [QuotaCheckError.DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201710}ApiExceptionFault:<message>[QuotaCheckError.DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']</message><ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type><errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="QuotaCheckError"><fieldPath/><trigger>&lt;null&gt;</trigger><errorString>QuotaCheckError.DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED</errorString><ApiError.Type>QuotaCheckError</ApiError.Type><reason>DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED</reason></errors>
```

I have gone through all the steps mentioned in 
[Request a developer token](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#request_a_developer_token)

and updated ads.properties file accordingly but still no luck

snippet of ads.properties file

```
api.adwords.developerToken=123axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
api.adwords.clientId=xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
api.adwords.clientSecret=zZxxxxxTxxxxxxxxxxx
api.adwords.clientCustomerId=123-456-7890
api.adwords.refreshToken=1/dyOIp7ki-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Can someone help me to make my code work
How long does it take to get standard API key.

Comment: Here is the description about that error message. I hope this is helpful. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/common-errors#QuotaCheckError.DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED

Answer (score 1):

Got it working after using different account because earlier i was trying to query MCC account which doesn't contain any campaigns and hence i created a new account and used that to query for campaigns and its working.